# Dynamically create and populate table in Android app

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm wondering how to dynamically create and populate a TableLayout in Android. I can create the table beforehand statically (via XML) but I need to be able to populate it with a dataset retrieved from a server when the application loads. The number of columns will always be the     same but the number of rows will change depending on the dataset retrieved.

What would be the best way to go about populating the table?

Comment: using a listview can work, depending on the shape of your table.

Comment: @njzk2 What do you mean? I need a vertical table with 3 columns spanning the whole width of the page. The table could potentially have thousands of rows.

Comment: if you have that many rows, a listview is definitely the way to go.

Comment: @njzk2 What advantages would a listview provide in this situation?

Comment: recycling views (used in adapterviews such as listview) means that to display 3 zillion items, you never need more actual views than you can fit on the screen, while a table layout would need 3 zillion views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the XML and code, for what could eventually be a File Manager Activity in Xamarin.Android. The ListView is populated by the FileAdapter.  The FileAdapter
keeps a list of FileSystemInfo objects, which is nice, because DirectoryInfo
and FileInfo classes are both of this type.  You should be able get the gist
of how a ListView works via this example.  My example is a bit more complicated
than the starter listview you'd see from the Xamarin site, because the list view
isn't the only view inside the display.  I have some buttons horizontally along
the top of the view. So that users can do extra commands.. I'm sorry that
I can't include the icons.  They are't my property to give away.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:background="@drawable/splash_image"
android:minHeight="25px">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <ImageButton
        android:src="@drawable/undo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1" />
    <ImageButton
        android:src="@drawable/addfolder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton3" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/folder"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="10dip"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="20dip" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<ListView
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@android:id/list" />
```

```
[Activity (Label = "Documents")]            
public class DocumentsActivity : ListActivity
{
    string path;
    ListView ourlist;
    TextView folder;
    ImageButton back;
    ImageButton home;
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.DocumentsActivity);

        back = FindViewById<ImageButton> (Resource.Id.imageButton1);


        back.Click += delegate {
            this.BackClick();
        };
        back.LongClick += delegate {
            UserHelper.BackButton(this);
        };

        ourlist = FindViewById<ListView> (Android.Resource.Id.List);
        folder = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.folder);

        path = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.ToString();
        folder.Text = "Folder: "+new DirectoryInfo (path).Name;
        ourlist.Adapter = new FileAdapter (path, this);
    }
    private void CreateFolder(string path)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists (path))
            Directory.CreateDirectory (path);
    }
    private void BackClick()
    {
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        ourlist.Adapter = new FileAdapter (dir.Parent.FullName, this);
        folder.Text = "Folder: "+dir.Parent.Name;

    } 
    protected override void OnListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
    {
        FileAdapter files = (FileAdapter)l.Adapter; 
        var t = files.Items[position];

        if (t is DirectoryInfo) {
        //Folder Behavior : 
            path = t.FullName;
            folder.Text = "Folder: "+t.Name;
            ourlist.Adapter = new FileAdapter (t.FullName,this);

        } else 
        {
        // File Behavior: (This is where will work will come in!)
            Android.Widget.Toast.MakeText (this, t.Name, Android.Widget.ToastLength.Short).Show ();
        }
    }
}



public class FileAdapter : BaseAdapter <FileSystemInfo>
{
    Activity _activity;
    string path;
    DirectoryInfo dir;

    public FileAdapter (string path,Activity act)
    {
        Items = new List<FileSystemInfo> ();
        dir = new DirectoryInfo (path);
        Items.AddRange (dir.GetDirectories().Where(z => !z.Name.StartsWith(".")).Cast<FileSystemInfo>().ToList());
        Items.AddRange (dir.GetFiles ());
        _activity = act;
    }

    public override FileSystemInfo this [int position] { 

        get { return Items[position]; }
    }
    public override int Count {
        get { return Items.Count() ; }
    }
    public override long GetItemId (int position)
    {
        return Items[position].GetHashCode();
    }

    public List<FileSystemInfo> Items {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public override View GetView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {           
        View view = convertView; 

        if (view == null)
            view = _activity.LayoutInflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.CustomView, null);

        if (Items [position] is DirectoryInfo) {
            ImageView imageview = view.FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.Image);
            imageview.SetImageResource (Resource.Drawable.Folder);
        } else {
            ImageView imageview = view.FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.Image);
            imageview.SetImageResource (Resource.Drawable.Files);
        }
        TextView text = view.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.Text1);
        text.Text = Items[position].Name;
        text.SetMinimumHeight (50);
        text.SetTextSize (Android.Util.ComplexUnitType.Pt, 10);

        return view;
    }
}
```