# Android/Monodroid - NotifyDataSetChange not refreshing view

Tags: c#, android, list, xamarin.android

I am using monodroid and trying to use NotifyDataSetChange. But when i invoke it on my listadapter it doesnt refresh the view.

My Code;

```
    CustomListAdapter listAdapter;
    ListView listView;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.customlist);

        listAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(this);
        listView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView);
        //Hook up our adapter to our ListView
        listView.Adapter = listAdapter;

        listView.ItemLongClick += listView_ItemLongClick;
    }

    void listView_ItemLongClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemLongClickEventArgs e)
    {

     var item = this.listAdapter.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position);

     deletevehicle(item);

    }


    private void deletevehicle(Vehicle v)
    {
        if (v != null)
        {
            VehicleDB.DeleteVehicle(v.ID);
            listAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

The list is populated by vehicles from my database just in case you are wondering, so I want it to be so that the vehicle is deleted, then the list is refreshed.

Thanks

Comment: You are not deleting it from the `Adapter`?

Comment: All I am doing is what is shown in the code, is there something else I should be doing?

Comment: Well I don't see it being deleted from the Item Source the `Adapter` holds. Does the `Adapter` somehow listen to the database? If so, how is it notified about what was deleted from it?

Comment: No, I have a List of vehicles, I populate the listadpater with that list. When delete vehicle is invoked, that vehicle is deleted, therefoe deleted from the list. I now need the listview to refresh with the new updated list

Comment: I don't see that anywhere in your code...

Comment: isnt that what  listAdapter.NotifyDatasetChanged is supposed to do (refresh the list) if not could you please show me what I am supposed to do?

Comment: NotifyDatasetChanged notifies the `Adapter` that you modified the internal Item Source. However nowhere in your code do I see you modifying that. Unless VehicleDB.DeleteVehicle does that and that is also what provides the Item Source internally.

Comment: OKay. so what do I do to refresh the listview...?

Comment: Is VehicleDB the backing store for the Adapter? If so it should be sufficient to just call NotifyDatasetChanged, assuming that the Adapter you use is implemented correctly.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35611/discussion-between-cam-connor-and-cheesebaron)

Comment: Yes and no, The adapter is being populated by a list and that list dirctly linked to the DB where it gets all the vehicles

Comment: If i leave the listview activity and then come back to it, it is updated the deleted vehicle is gone, how can i replicate this without leaving the actvity

Comment: Could you just show us how you implement the `CustomListAdapter`?

Answer (score 0):

You could always re-instantiate your ListAdapater to a new instance.  Assuming that your delete method interacts with a web service.. and causes the data change you need.  I'd recommend using a dialog while the data is refreshed.

```
private void deletevehicle(Vehicle v)
{
    if (v != null)
    {
        //Raise up a progress dialog here
        //I'm assuming that VehicleDB.DeleteVehicle is actually interacting with a service, 
        //or deleting the record from a local sqllite db.
        VehicleDB.DeleteVehicle(v.ID);
        listAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(this);
        //Make the progress Dialog invisible again
    }
}
```

Comment: Then you need to verify that your listadapter really does fetch the right data, or that your delete method truly works because a new instance of the Adapter, if you really did delete your record, should return a shorter list.  This link is to some code for a "DocumentActivity". Could be expanded a bit to Manage files. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18143358/dynamically-create-and-populate-table-in-android-app/18163364#18163364